# Python regex string value to end of file

Tags: python, regex

Log file there i want to read the last few lines after the request fails :

the log file have request logged and rest is traceback, i want whole traceback and request last entry only.  my request has 'cookies' in it so I'm using it in regex for find the line but I want it to be last entry only for that nothing works.

logfile entry :

```
[22/Jul/2014:10:41:01.91] --- {'cookies': {'_sdsdsds': 'MzEzMzI1NDQ2OQ==', 'BBAUTHTOKEN': 'MPh5Kva9g3YqjSFx/VdnN757ImRldmljZV9pZCI6ICJiZTUxZDFlZTY0NmMyY2Q4IiwgImNoYWZmIjogInJ3ajdkTUFYamhGN3FnPT1cbiIsICJtaWQiOiA1NDMzMSwgInZpZ etc' }} 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/admin.py", line 271, in some_method
OperationalError: (1205, 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction')

other log entries

[22/Jul/2014:10:41:10.00] --- {'cookies': {'_sdsdsds': 'MzEzMzI1NDQ2OQ==', 'BBAUTHTOKEN': 'MPh5Kva9g3YqjSFx/VdnN757ImRldmljZV9pZCI6ICJiZTUxZDFlZTY0NmMyY2Q4IiwgImNoYWZmIjogInJ3ajdkTUFYamhGN3FnPT1cbiIsICJtaWQiOiA1NDMzMSwgInZpZ etc' }} 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/admin.py", line 271, in some_method
OperationalError: (1205, 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction')
```

Code:

```
 f ='logfile'
 for line in f.readlines():
    match = re.search( 'cookies', line, re.M|re.I)
    if match:
        print match.group(), line
        break
```

Comment: example would be better.

Comment: its log file with lots of entries like this but want to create alert message from only the last entry and traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here: firstly you are using the string 'logfile' instead of opening a file, secondly you are iterating through the file by line while trying to extract multi-line strings.

So to start with try:

```
with open('logfile', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        match = re.search('cookies', line, re.M|re.I)
        if match:
            print match.group(), line
            break
```

to properly open the file.

Next we then you'll need to worry about extracting multiple lines at once. What we really want to do is iterate over log file entries instead of lines in the for loop. How to do this depends on the log file's syntax (and if you are allowed to modify the syntax). For example if the log entries are separated by a blank line you can just do:

```
def log_entries(f):
    return f.read().split('\n\n')

def main():
    with open('logfile', 'r') as f:
        for log_entry in log_entries(f):
            match = re.search('cookies', log_entry, re.M|re.I)
            if match:
                print(match.group(), log_entry)
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

This what I did :

```
def find_last(FILE_PATH):
flag = 0
tmp_lines = []
f = open(FILE_PATH)
for line in reversed(f.readlines()):
    if flag == 1:
        tmp_lines.append(line)
    match = re.search('cookies', line, re.M | re.I)
    if match:
        if flag:
            return tmp_lines
        flag = 1
        tmp_lines.append(line)
```

it still gives list in reverse order so again have to reverse it to get correct one